# Outlook Macro to get recipients of an appointment

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get all the recipients "list of people in TO: .. section" of an outlook appointment that I select.

I need the subject and and the recipients of all the selected appointments, I could get the subject but am not able to get the recipients. Below is the code I tried..

```
Sub testCode()

Dim objItem As Object
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

Set objApp = Application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.workbooks.Open "C:\data.xlsm"
For i = 1 To 49

    Set objItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)

    xlApp.Range("A" & i & "").Value = objItem.Subject
    xlApp.Range("B" & i & "").Value = objItem.To  // not working

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Use for each recipient in a [Recipients collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `To` field in an appointment.  There are required attendees and optional attendees.

Use these properties:

```
objItem.OptionalAttendees
```

and

```
objItem.RequiredAttendees
```

As a sidenote, the easiest way to figure out things like this is to examine the object in the locals window of the code window while stepping through the code.  This way you can see all of the properties that the object has and figure out what to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AppointmentItem.Recipients` collection and loop through all recipients. Recipient.Type = olTo are required, olCC - optional, olBCC - resources.